# Question on non-continuous derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, fake-proofs

> Let's assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and its derivative $f'(x)$ is not continuous. Applying the mean value theorem we get:
> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(\xi), \text{ where } a<\xi<x.
> $$

Now the claim is that $f'(\xi(x))$ is continuous.

At each point $x\neq a$ this follows directly from the rules of continuous functions. If we set $f'(\xi(a)):=f'(a)$ and choose a sufficiently small $\delta>0$ then for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ we see that:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon, \text{ because }f \text{ is differentiable}.
$$
Hence, $f'(\xi(x))$ is continuous.

---

Further, we see that $x\to a\implies \xi\to a$. So $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f'(\xi(x))=\lim\limits_{\xi\to a} f'(\xi) = f'(a)$. How is this possible if $f'(x)$ is not continuous?

Comment: Are you assuming $f'$ is not continuous at only one point $a$? Also I think you claim that $x \mapsto \xi(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \{a\}$, why would it be?

Comment: @blamethelag, I assume that $f'$ is not continuous on its domain $\mathbb{R}$. It might be that it is nowhere continuous but it also might be that it is continuous at some points. I don't see that this would matter here. Why do I assume that $\xi(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{a\}$? I only use the fact that if I shrink the intervall $(a,x)$ then $\xi(x)$ necessarily goes to $a$. That is how the mean vakue theorem is defined.

Comment: You should fix your notations and state what is $a$. You just proved that $f’ \circ \xi $ is continuous at $a$. Also it can happend that a function $g$ does not have a limit at some point $x_0$ but for some $h$ with limit $x_0$ at, say, $y_0$, $g \circ h$ has a limit at $y_0$.

Comment: @blamethelag , I am not sure what you mean... it's clear that $a$ is simply a given point which doesn't change over the course and I have not only shown  that $f'\circ \xi$ is continuous at $a$ but also at every other point $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You said $f' \circ \xi$ is continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \{a\}$ because of the rules of continuous functions. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @blamethelag rules of continuous functions: if you know that $g,h$ are two continuous functions then $h+g$,$h-g$, $f\cdot g$ are continuous functions. If $g\neq 0 $ then $\frac{f}{g}$ is also continuous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131617/discussion-between-blamethelag-and-philipp).